# Arc length of a curve which already has an integral sign

Tags: integration

This one here was tricky because the function already has an integral sign. My guess is that I need to evaluate the indegral where $x=4$ so that i get $y=f(t)$ and after that apply the Arc Length Forumla. Am I on the right track?

> $$ y = \int_1^x \sqrt{t^3-1} \ \ dt \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1 \leq x \leq 4$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: You do **not** need to evaluate the integral. Recall that in the arc length formula, the function's *derivative* appears, then apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Take  $\ \ \ f(x) = \int_1^x \sqrt{t^3-1} \ dt $
Since integrand is continous, you can write
$\ \ f'(x) = \sqrt{x^3-1} $
Now apply the arc length formula.